# Android app XML data structure

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I am building an Android Application which has multiple modules and each module has ~25 lessons. Each lesson has data associated with it such as instructions, images ,and other data. I decided to store everything in XML and then parse it. 
How should i structure the XML? Should I be making different xml files for each module, or 1 xml file that contains all modules and the lessons within it. 
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Why not using Json instead?It s lighter,neater and easier to handle.And also I suggest that each module should has its own json file.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For future development and code readability, it is advisable that you split each of your content into different XML.  And this promote faster code processing too.